# Why is Gecko Driver (v0.17.0 - x64bit) not opening Browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

Why is Gecko Driver (v0.17.0 - x64bit) not opening Browser?

**Base Page / Method:**

```
public BasePage loadUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    driver.get(url);
    return new BasePage(driver);
}
```

**Cucumber Step:**

```
@Given("^User navigates to the \"([^\"]*)\" website$")
public void user_navigates_to_the_website(String url) throws Throwable {
   BasePage basePage = new BasePage(driver);
   basePage.loadUrl(url);
}
```

**Driver Factory:**

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    try {
        if(driver == null){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);
        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        }
   return driver;
}
```

**NEW CODE - Driver Factory:** uses if statements to point to exe files for each browser type:

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
        try {
            ReadConfigFile file = new ReadConfigFile();
            if (driver == null) {
                if("chrome".equalsIgnoreCase(file.getBrowser())){
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
                if("firefox".equalsIgnoreCase(file.getBrowser())){
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
                }
                if("ie".equalsIgnoreCase(file.getBrowser())){
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constant.IE_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Post the stacktrace

Comment: @Madhan im getting 'Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at utils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:29)' but with chrime driver the setup works

Comment: It seems that you haven't initialized the driver properly. nullpointer error is regarding driver initilization follow the same steps as you have done for chrome as you are saying chrome is working

Comment: @Trimantra Software Solution i have used the exact same steps as Chrome very weird why not working

Comment: can you show up the code for chrome ?

Comment: sure @Trimantra Software Solution i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

fixed upgrading to **Selenium version: 3.4.0**